# Prevent existing Activity from flashing when changing Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, commit

I am experiencing an issue where the previous fragment on my stack displays when transitioning to another fragment on low end devices.

Lets say I have three fragments on my stack; A, B and C. From fragment C I am starting fragment A, but I am seeing fragment B before fragment A loads. Is there any way to prevent this, other than using a transition which seems to do the trick.

I guess I am hoping there is some attribute that might be useful in this scenario. Here is how I am making my fragment transitions.

```
private void fragReplaceContentFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean withBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(contentFragmentContainer.getId(), fragment, String.valueOf(fragment.hashCode()));
    if (withBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();` by `transaction.commit();` and give a feedback here.

Comment: How would that fix the problem?

Comment: Allowing state loss during a commit has what to do with the question?

Comment: @SilentKnight, your answer does not help me. That does not prevent the issue I am facing. Thank  you for giving an answer though.